# Woocommerce: unnecessary bullets appear to shipping options

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've built my soon-to-be-launched online shop on Wordpress, theme Ellie, using Woocommerce plugin.

The issue appears in the Shipping options: unnecessary bullets and indentation is added to each Shipping option. You can see it in Cart for example.

[image]

I tried to search how I can **remove these bullets** and move the shipping options more to the left side but found nothing.

Hope someone could advice (as easy way possible to fix as I'm not a developer).

https://senjacosmetics.com/shop/

Comment: https://senjacosmetics.com/shop/

Comment: all product on your site is out of stock i can't add the product to cart to check your css, and please put your site in your question instead of the comment

Comment: Managed to do that. There is now stock for 1 product.

Comment: i can see only DHL shipping method without the bullets

Comment: If you try location Finland for example, then it gives more shipping options. Vattuniemenkatu 16, zip 00210, city Helsinki, country Finland

Answer (score 1):

just add the following to your custom css and you are ready to go :

```
ul#shipping_method {
list-style: none !important;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: Yess, that removed the bullets! Is it possible to also align the text to the left side? And how? Now it's aligned to the right side and breaks the text to 2 rows.

Comment: actually they are  already align left but the problem you have with the div width which is forcing the shipping desc to be wrapped to new line, but you can use `white-space: nowrap;`  but that might make the product title to be wrapped to new line

Comment: try the following and tell me if that might help u a bit `ul#shipping_method li { white-space: nowrap;
}`

Comment: Yes, now everything is neatly in one line. Thanks a lot for your help, you are a legend! I used hours trying to solve this myself, what a waste of time :)

Comment: you are welcome :) if my answer was satisfied to you please mark it as solved and up voted :)